# Django ReST Framework - Extended User model not accepting "null=true"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have checked a lot of similar questions but no one has encountered such an issue in django shell :

I am using Django 2 and DRF 3.7.7 with Python 3.6 and PostgreSQL 10.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am writing a booking application and trying to extend Django user model with OneToOneField (Using the guide [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) without using Signals' methods). I have had some experiences coding in Python 2.7 for some time, but this is my first experience with Django.

So here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

SPORTS_CHOICES = (
    ('Mountain', 'Mountain climbing'),
    ('Offroad', 'Offroad Driving'),
    ('Rafting', 'Rafting'),
    ('Cycling', 'Cycling'),
    ('Ski', 'Skiing'),
)


class ListField(models.TextField):

    "ListField stores List of element"

    SPLIT_CHAR= ';'

    def __init__(self, *args, list_choices=None, **kwargs):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if list_choices is None:
            list_choices = []
        self.list_choices = list_choices

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None or value == "":
            return None
        res = self.SPLIT_CHAR.join(value)
        return res

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_prep_value(value)


class Profile(models.Model):

    "The Profile of a user with details are stored in this model."

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=11)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=50,null=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=100,null=True)

    # The default username is phone number (Ver. 1.0)

    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=11,default=user)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    interests = ListField(choices=SPORTS_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('User','Normal User'),
        ('Leader','Tour Leader'),
        ('Admin','Administrator'),
    )
    user_type = models.TextField(choices=USER_TYPES)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    official_docs = models.ImageField(default='../Static/1.jpeg')
    group_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    debit_card_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    favorite_music = ListField( null=True)
```

As you can see in the above code, it is basically Django User model extended by a couple of different data types. (Off the topic, but I'm trying to use phone number as username, but it does not accept user.username as default value in phone_number field, why?) Now the problem is, whenever I want to save my model through shell, using only mandatory fields and leaving the fields with "null=true":

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username='01234567890')
>>> test = Profile.objects.create(user=user,gender='M',city='NY',interests='[Ski]',user_type='User')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, null, Booking.Profile.user, ../Static/1.jpeg, M, NY, null, [;S;k;i;], 2018-02-24, User, 2018-02-24 05:18:54.256013+00, ../Static/1.jpeg, null, null, null, 15).


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, null, Booking.Profile.user, ../Static/1.jpeg, M, NY, null, [;S;k;i;], 2018-02-24, User, 2018-02-24 05:18:54.256013+00, ../Static/1.jpeg, null, null, null, 15).
>>> user = User.objects.create_user(username='01234567890')
>>> test = Profile.objects.create(user=user,gender='M',city='NY',interests='[Ski]',user_type='User')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, null, Booking.Profile.user, ../Static/1.jpeg, M, NY, null, [;S;k;i;], 2018-02-24, User, 2018-02-24 05:18:54.256013+00, ../Static/1.jpeg, null, null, null, 15).


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/amir/.virtualenvs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, null, null, Booking.Profile.user, ../Static/1.jpeg, M, NY, null, [;S;k;i;], 2018-02-24, User, 2018-02-24 05:18:54.256013+00, ../Static/1.jpeg, null, null, null, 15).
```

But when I give them values, I am able to allocate the model, save the model and even serialize the data (I haven't copied the serializer class as its just a simple serializer inherited from ModelSerializer and there is no issue with that, so its a bit off-topic):

```
>>> test = Profile.objects.create(user=user,first_name='Amir',last_name='Amir',gender='M',city='NY',description='',interests='[Ski]',group_name='',debit_card_number='1',favorite_music='1',user_type='User')
>>> test.save()
>>> print(repr(test))
<Profile: Profile object (11)>
>>> serial = ProfileSerializer(test)
>>> print(repr(serial.data))
{'user': 15, 'first_name': 'Amir', 'last_name': 'Amir', 'phone_number': 'Manjaro.Profile.user', 'avatar': '../Static/1.jpeg', 'gender': 'M', 'city': 'NY', 'description': '', 'interests': '[Ski]', 'date_of_birth': '2018-02-24', 'user_type': 'User', 'join_date': '2018-02-24T05:44:00.188963Z', 'official_docs': '../Static/1.jpeg', 'group_name': '', 'debit_card_number': 1, 'favorite_music': '1'}
```

I know there are a couple of other issues, but this one has worried me a lot. I can have a workaround and save some default values, but I need some of them to be left blank. 
Also, interesting point is, ImageField does not have any issue with being blank! Also for a field called "group_name" I'm just passing an empty string and seems python/django is OK with that! Is there a set of attributes to be set? Do I have to assign default values? Am I doing something wrong or taking the wrong approach using OneToOneField? Please help!

Comment: It could be that in the db the column is defined as 'default='', not null' which would be why strings( even empty since an empty string is not NULL ) are getting inserted. Please check the column in the db if its been defined as 'default not null' or 'default null'. Also as per this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#s-field-options its not a good idea to define null=True for text fields, try blank=True instead ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've already checked the db. The fields are defined "default null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so according to you question, if you want to have null values in the model fields then you ave to specify `null=True, blank=True` blank is also important when using in forms. Do you have generated (and applied) all migrations? 
field to store almost every type of data you want).

Moreover, [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) state:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField unless you have an excellent reason. If a string-based field
>   has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”:
>   NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two
>   possible values for “no data;” Django convention is to use the empty
>   string, not NULL.

Then according to your code, you have created `class ListField(models.TextField)` which stores list of elements. Please have a look on [PostgreSQL specific model fields | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). There is `ArrayField` already implemented in Django which you can use. (Also `JSONfield` which can store almost every type of data you want.)

Comment: Thanks! Using blank=True and default='', all of the non-null issues are resolved!

Comment: @aLuViAn Happy to hear that!

Comment: I tried using ArrayField like this :     favorite_music = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True,default='[]')) And I get the same "not-null" error again. I used ArrayField on two occasions, the first one was OK, but the latter - which is above - is preventing me from creating the profile object. Is there something wrong? I tried with default='' and it does not work either.

Comment: above comment is for you, sorry I'm new to StackOverflow and didn't mention you on the previous comment. @Krystofee

Comment: @aLuViAn You forgot to add `null=True` probably.